# Numerical optimization question

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

I need to solve the following optimization problem. 
\begin{aligned}
    \min_{\lambda_0,\lambda_1} & \sum_{t=1}^T\sum_{n\in\{4,8,12,16\}} \left(\frac{1}{n}A_n + \frac{1}{n}B_n^\top X_t + y_t^{(n)}\right)^2 \\
    \text{s.t.  }\\
    & A_{n+1} = A_n + B_n^\top(\mu - \Sigma\lambda_0) + \frac{1}{2}B_n^\top\Sigma\Sigma^\top B_n, & n=1,\dots,16 \\
    & B_{n+1} = (\Phi - \Sigma\lambda_1)^\top B_n - \begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      0 \\
      0
    \end{bmatrix}, & n=1,\dots,16 \\
    & A_1 = 0, \qquad B_1 = -\begin{bmatrix}
      1 \\
      0 \\
      0
    \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{aligned}
where $B_n$ is $3\times 1$, $A_n$ is a scalar and $\Phi,\mu, \Sigma,y_t^{(n)}, X_t, \;t=1,\dots,T$ are given. $\Phi,\Sigma$ are $3\times3$ and $\mu, X_t$ are $3\times1$.

Unknown variables are $\lambda_0$ which is $3\times1$ and $\lambda_1$ which is $3\times 3$.

I'm familiar with Matlab, Matematica, R. Which software can I use? Which functions? How do I program it, a Lagrangian with a many constraints? Is there other method of solving such problems?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. At a first glance I thought the constraints were affine. Will delete comment momentarily.

Comment: Is the evolution of some dynamical system? (I mean, something straightforward.)

Comment: It is a dynamic system (affine term structure model from finance). The idea is to select two parameters $\lambda_0,\lambda_1$, so that the model fits data the best.

Comment: Sometimes such problems can be formulated as an optimal control problem which may have simpler optimality characterizations...

Comment: Just to double check: are $\lambda$ the only variables?

Comment: @Dominique. Yes, the rest are known.

Comment: I changed \underset{\lamba_0,\lambda_1}{\min} to \min_{\lamba_0,\lambda_1}.  In a "displayed" (rather than "inline") setting, that has the same effect and is less complicated.

Comment: @Affine It seems to me that your problem is a convex quadratic program. You'll need to declare the $\hat{y}$ as variables, with the first constraint defining them. Look through the documentation of Matlab, Mathematica and R to see what they have for convex quadratic programming. Since you only have equality constraints, you'll find the solution by solving a single system of linear equations. So another way to go about it is to formulate the KKT conditions and solve that linear system (e.g., using Matlab's `ldl()`).

Comment: @ Dominique. Thanks, I'll think about it. I simplified problem a little and updated post.

Answer (score 0):

If you already use MATLAB and the problem is indeed convex (haven't checked in detail) you could try [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is an "EQP" (an Equality-Constrained Quadratic Program). It has a convex quadratic objective and linear equality constraints, i.e., it has the general form
$$
\min_x \ c^T x + \tfrac{1}{2} x^T H x \quad \text{subject to} \ Ax=b,
$$
where $H$ is a symmetric and positive semi-definite matrix. It turns out that solving EQPs is just a matter of linear algebra since any solution is a global minimizer and also solves the linear system
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
 H & A^T \\
 A & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 x \\ y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
 -c \\ b
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $y$ is the vector of Lagrange multipliers associated to the equality constraints. The matrix of this system is symmetric and indefinite so in Matlab you can use `ldl()` to factorize it. If it's very large and/or very dense, you can also use `minres()` to solve the system. But judging from your post, a simple "backslash" might do.